# Objective-C: Which view to use? (Looking for opinions)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I am a co-op student who has been tasked with making an app (for iPads) to replace paper&pencil checklists that are currently being used.  I have all the functionality done (I've made a different app for each pice of funcationailty) and now its time to bring it all together.

The only thing is that I am not sure what view I should use.  I want the app to open, then a list of all the checksheets to come up. I think that a Navigation-based Application would be best, but its only for iPhone applications.

I thought about using a Split View-based Application, but I don't like how the side menu lingers around; after my users select a checklist, they will not need to select another, so there is no need for the side menu to be there anymore.  Also, all of the examples of Split View-based Applications I've seen use an array to store different images, then display those.  I would need to have an array of views.  Is this even possible?  Each one of my checklists will have a different amount of fields and etc, so I will be making a different view for each one.

Basically, I am looking if anyone has created a similar app, and what they did to organize the interface.

Thanks.

Edit:  I should also add the Tab Bar is out of the question; I don't want users accidently switching to a different tab while they are filling out a checklist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a split view controller would be good. If you want, you can cause the master view to be automatically hidden in both orientations by implementing a delegate for your split view controller and returning YES from the `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:` method. (Then you can have the standard swipe or pressing some other button re-show it.)

Comment: This might be what I am looking for.  When you hide the menu in landscape view will the tab to swipe it automatically be there ?

Comment: I don't believe it shows a tab; you just swipe in from the edge. Since that's not very obvious, Apple's sample code typically creates a bar button item which also shows the master view (like in iPad Mail in portrait).